# How to add a line break and space in TextView?

Tags: android

I am setting following string as a input for my txtMessage :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.breaknotification);

    TextView txtMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    String msg = "TIME   RECORD        VALUE\n" +
                 "10 AM    1            20\n"+
                 "11 AM    2            30\n"+
                 "12 PM    3            40";

    txtMessage.setText(msg);

}
```

my breaknotification.xml file is as per following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to print my string as per following format.

```
TIME   RECORD     VALUE
10 AM     1        20
11 AM     2        30
12 PM     3        40
```

But it is not showing me exactly what I want; it shows me following in my message,

```
TIME     RECORD      VALUE
`10 AM    1       20`
`11 AM    2       30`
`12 PM    3       40`
```

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you cleaned and built your project? I am pretty sure what you are doing is right and I'd have done the same.

Comment: yes i cleaned but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution :
added textView property : android:typeface="monospace"

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:text=""
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:typeface="monospace"
  android:textSize="21sp"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
txt_Message.setText("TIME    RECORD    VALUE \n10 AM   1    20 \n11 AM   2    30 \n12 PM   3    40");
```

Comment: Try it with smaller text for example **Hi\nThere** and check if it works, if so it means there is problems with your spacing in the text

Comment: Ok first restart eclipse maybe its glitching, then try, if still same problem, delete the textview in your layout, recreate it and make sure layout_width and layout_height are wrap_content and try

Comment: You didn't mention on what you are debugging, is it the emulator, or debug mobile?

Comment: its Tablet - Samsung Galaxy 10" (Android version 3.2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is you answer :

```
txt_Message.setText("TIME    RECORD    VALUE \n10 AM   1    20 \n11 AM   2    30 \n12 PM   3    40");
```

You can also use HTML code in a textView with Html.fromHtml :

```
txt_Message.setText(Html.fromHtml("Test<br>Text2"));
```

It is not the best to use but it will let you have a linebreak too.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i dont want to use Html tags in string input.

Comment: Try it with smaller text for example **Hi\nThere** and check if it works, if so it means there is problems with your spacing in the text

Comment: It is not working ? Maybe you have a singleLine = "true" on your textView.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_Message.setText("TIME\tRECORD\tVALUE\n10 AM\t1\t20\n11 AM\t2\t30\n12 PM\t3\t40");
```

can u try tab characters?